# Read the embed PDF file in Excel using Aspose.Cells

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, aspose-cells

I'm trying to read **PDF** files in **Excel** and save it to local using **Aspose.Cells** for **C#**, 
but when I read the PDF's *ObjectSourceFullName* , it's "*. bin", and other attributes also not show anything identify it's PDF.
How this happened and how to solve this? 
Please help me,  Thanks!!!

Comment: So, you're trying to extract a PDF embedded inside an Excel file into a standalone PDF file?

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the type of OLE object with its **ClassIdentifier** property. It is a 16-bytes number. Convert it to GUID and then check what this GUID means inside the Windows Registry.

```
Guid guid = new Guid(wb.Worksheets[0].OleObjects[0].ClassIdentifier);
```

The following screenshot explains that **{b801ca65-a1fc-11d0-85ad-444553540000}** actually means **Adobe Acrobat Document**.

[image]

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose